# Silverlight multi-page with browser back/forwards

Tags: silverlight

I can present multiple pages in Silverlight using

```
Content = new DetailsPage();
```

However is this can be confusing to a user who may not even know the page is in Silverlight and would be expecting to hit the back button on the browser.
Obviously I can add my own buttons but this doesn't seem right.

**How can I allow "normal" browser navigation using the back/forwards button?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight 2, you can still handle navigation.  It's just a more manual process.

Call

```
HtmlPage.Window.NavigateToBookmark("blah");
```

to add the "#blah" to the end of the URL.
Call

```
string bookmark = HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark;
```

to find out where you currently are.  People are also tying into jquery/Asp.net AJAX libraries to use their navigation support.

In Silverlight 3, you can use the Navigation Framework to do some of this automatically.  File->New Project->Silverlight Navigation Project.

Answer (score 0):

You should really formulate a question.

I'll assume that you want to know how to achieve multi-page navigation with browser back-button support.

There one simple answer, which is to use [Silverlight 3](http://silverlight.net/learn/videocat.aspx?cat=12#sl3) where it is supported out of the box, as well as in-app navigation using the address bar.

Release date is set for july 10, so there's not much longer to wait.
Be careful, you cannot at the moment install both Silverlight 2 and 3 on one machine, and there is no end-user plugin available (only developper runtimes, to install manually).

Comment: Ok, so I will then use the Navigation Farmework? Put a ref. to that in your answer and I will accept it. Cheers!